# CMP/BEQ not working Always branching (ARM)

Tags: if-statement, assembly, arm

I'm getting very mad at this and can't figure out why my BEQ statement is always executed.
The program should replace char located in memory(Address in RO)

```
_ should become +
C should become A
A should become B
B should become C
```

This is what I have so far (sorry french comments):

```
  MOV R11, #0                   ; Initialise le nombe de copie fait
  MOV R10, #43                  ; R10 = +
  MOV R9, #'_'                  ; R9 = _
  MOV R8, #'A'                  ; R8 = A
  MOV R7, #'B'                  ; R7 = B
  MOV R6, #'C'                  ; R6 = C



  TOP:                          
      LDRB R5, [R0, R11]         ; Copie element X dans R5

      CMP R5, R9
      BEQ PLUS

      CMP R5, R8
      BEQ A

      CMP R5, R7
      BEQ B

      CMP R5, R6
      BEQ C

      PLUS:                             ; Branchement si _
           STRB R10, [R0, R11]  
      A:                                ; Branchement si A
           STRB R8, [R0, R11]                                   
      B:                                ; Branchement si B
           STRB R7, [R0, R11]     
      C:                                ; Branchement si C
           STRB R6, [R0, R11]     

      ADDS R11, R11, #1           ; ++nbcopiefait
      CMP R11, R1                 ; Validation de la condition
  BNE TOP
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's not only C's `switch()` that confuses people...
So, what you're currently doing is the equivalent of

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  switch(chararray[i])
    {
      default:
      case '_': chararray[i] = '+';
      case 'C': chararray[i] = 'A';
      case 'A': chararray[i] = 'B';
      case 'B': chararray[i] = 'C';
    }
}
```

You're missing the `break;` after every `case`.
Edit, because it seems I have to make it really obvious:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  switch(chararray[i])
    {
      default:
        break;
      case '_': chararray[i] = '+';
        break;
      case 'C': chararray[i] = 'A';
        break;
      case 'A': chararray[i] = 'B';
        break;
      case 'B': chararray[i] = 'C';
        break;                     //unnecessary, but I put it in for regularity
    }
}
```

Comment: how/where should I break ?

Comment: There. Before you ask me to write the corresponding assembly for you, I don't speak ARM.

Comment: Ok, I wrote the code in C and trying to decipher the break in dissasembly but can't find it

Comment: It's an unconditional jump to incrementing `i`, followed by an unconditional jump to the `for-loop` condition `i < n`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [EOF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26812593/3156750), you can see what's going on by tracing through a sample execution instruction-by-instruction - a debugger always helps, but this is simple enough to do by hand. Let's consider a couple of different situations:

```
      Instruction            case char=='A'         case char=='Z'
      -------------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      LDRB R5, [R0, R11]     executes, r5='A'       executes, r5='Z'
      CMP R5, R9             executes, flags=ne     executes, flags=ne
      BEQ PLUS               flags!=eq, not taken   flags!=eq, not taken
      CMP R5, R8             executes, flags=eq     executes, flags=ne
      BEQ A                  flags==eq, taken       flags!=eq, not taken
      CMP R5, R7                      /             executes, flags=ne
      BEQ B                          /              flags!=eq, not taken
      CMP R5, R6                    /               executes, flags=ne
      BEQ C                        /                flags!=eq, not taken
PLUS: STRB R10, [R0, R11]         V                 executes: oops!
A:    STRB R8, [R0, R11]     executes               executes: oops!
B:    STRB R7, [R0, R11]     executes: oops!        executes: oops!
C:    STRB R6, [R0, R11]     executes: oops!        executes: oops!
      ADDS R11, R11, #1      executes               executes
      ...
```

So no matter what happens, everything ends up as 'C' regardless! (note there's a register mixup for 'A', 'B', and 'C' - if you match r8, you jump to storing r8, etc.) Implementing the equivalent of `break` is a case of making sure instructions are skipped when you *don't* want them executing:

```
      ...
      CMP R5, R6
      BEQ C
      B LOOP             ; no match, skip everything
PLUS: STRB R10, [R0, R11]
      B LOOP             ; we've stored '_', skip 'B', 'C', and 'A'
A:    STRB R7, [R0, R11]
      B LOOP             ; we've stored 'B', skip 'C' and 'A'
B:    STRB R6, [R0, R11]
      B LOOP             ; we've stored 'C', skip 'A'
C:    STRB R8, [R0, R11] ; nothing to skip, just fall through to the loop
LOOP: ADDS R11, R11, #1
      ...
```

However, note that unlike most architectures, ARM's conditional execution applies to most instructions. Thus an alternative approach, given a small number of simple routines (1-3 instructions) is to actually *remove* all the branches, and let conditional execution take care of it:

```
...
LDRB R5, [R0, R11]
CMP R5, R9
STRBEQ R10, [R0, R11]
CMP R5, R8
STRBEQ R7, [R0, R11]
CMP R5, R7
STRBEQ R6, [R0, R11]
CMP R5, R6
STRBEQ R8, [R0, R11]
ADDS R11, R11, #1
...
```

That way, everything gets "executed", but any stores which fail their condition check just do nothing.